# delete the rows of my dataframe if not contained

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe, and a list of numbers(ages). I want to delete the rows of my dataframe, if the ages are not contained in my list.

Here is my dataframe as df

```
      Sex  Age
0    male   22
1  female   38
2  female   26
3  female   35
4    male   35
5    male   27
```

A list of numbers(ages)

```
list=[22,26,27]
```

Desired output

```
      Sex  Age
0    male   22
1  female   26
2    male   27
```

I have tried

```
for i in range(0, len(df)):
  for j in range(0, len(listofAge)):
    if(df["Age"][i]!=listofAge[j]): 
      df.drop[df.index[i]]


print(df)
```

Comment: i remember seeing a similar question before, this is a dupe, let me know if you cant make the duplicate link work and please dont name the variable as list else it will override the default list builtin

Comment: Use `df.loc[df['Age'].isin(list_), :]`

Comment: You can use `isin` or `query` to do this.